# GetRawInputDeviceList fails with error 87 (Incorrect parameters)

Tags: winapi, ada, raw-input

I am having a problem calling Raw Input functions for my 64 bit application that worked fine before I switched from 32 bit. I have no idea what the sizes of the parameters need to be or why they changed when I switched the bit size. Specifically the first call I make to the API is GetRawInputDeviceList which fails with error code 87. I would like to get this working in 64 bit but I have tried everything (type casting pointers etc) without success.

It is very similar to this problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23414edf-0288-4148-98ef-1a03742a6ef8/raw-input-x64-api-question-getrawinputdevicelist-call-fails-in-windows-7-x64?forum=libraryfeedback

EDIT: Code from my project

```
function Get_Device_List(
  List  : in Address; -- Assume 8 byte pointer
  Count : in Address; -- Assume 8 byte pointer
  Size  : in Integer_4_Unsigned_C) -- Assume 4 byte integer
  return Integer_4_Unsigned_C;
pragma Import(Stdcall, Get_Device_List, "GetRawInputDeviceList");
Assert(Get_Device_List( -- works for 32 bit applications
  List  => NULL_ADDRESS,
  Count => Number_Of_X'address,
  Size  => Record_Device_List_Element'size / Byte'size) /= -1);
```

Comment: 1. Type casting pointers is never the solution.  If you have type casts in the 32-bit code, that's probably where you ran into porting problems.  2.  You didn't show any code, so we cannot possibly help you.

Comment: 1. I tried type casting because simply calling the 64 bit version of the function did not work. 2. All I am trying to do is call the 64 bit function, if someone can call the 64 bit function as it is documented and tell me how the function is changed based on bit size I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `(<dtype rid="UINT"/>)-1)`  doesn't look like C++ code.  Make a new Win32 console project, paste the example in along with including `<windows.h>`, give us the *exact* same code you're using, and tell us what is going wrong for you.

Comment: What does **your code** look like?  Copying+pasting the sample code from MSDN doesn't help—that's obviously not the code you're using.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  I'll make a small modification to my test that will probably help you a whole bunch...

Comment: Do the structure and field sizes in my answer help at all?  Be careful, there's padding in the structure to keep 8-byte alignment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an extremely simple working example, which shows the size and layout of the structure on x64 Windows.

```
C:\Users\Ben\Documents\SO>type rawinputdevicelist.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    UINT nDevices;
    PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList;
    auto retval = GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &nDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
    auto errval = GetLastError();
    printf("sizeof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST) is %d\n", (int)sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
    printf("offsetof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST::hDevice) is %d\n", (char*)(&pRawInputDeviceList->hDevice) - (char*)pRawInputDeviceList);
    printf("sizeof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST::hDevice) is %d\n", (int)(sizeof pRawInputDeviceList->hDevice));
    printf("offsetof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST::dwType) is %d\n", (char*)(&pRawInputDeviceList->dwType) - (char*)pRawInputDeviceList);
    printf("sizeof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST::dwType) is %d\n", (int)(sizeof pRawInputDeviceList->dwType));
    printf("\nGetRawInputDeviceList() returned %d\n", (int)retval);
    printf("GetLastError() returned %d\n", (int)errval);
    printf("nDevices = %u\n", (unsigned int)nDevices);
    return 0;
}

C:\Users\Ben\Documents\SO>cl rawinputdevicelist.cpp user32.lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.30501 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

rawinputdevicelist.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.30501.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:rawinputdevicelist.exe
rawinputdevicelist.obj
user32.lib

C:\Users\Ben\Documents\SO>rawinputdevicelist
sizeof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST) is 16
offsetof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST::hDevice) is 0
sizeof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST::hDevice) is 8
offsetof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST::dwType) is 8
sizeof (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST::dwType) is 4

GetRawInputDeviceList() returned 0
GetLastError() returned 0
nDevices = 9
```

Comment: That is very helpful! That is 16 bytes correct? I am getting a size of RAWINPUTDEVICELIST as 12 for 64 bit and 8 for 32 bit. What do you get with 32 bit compilation as the size?

Comment: I apologize again for not explaining myself. Thanks for the answer and quick replies.

Comment: @RogerWilco: I may not know Ada... but I do know exactly what bits of information you need to match the structure layout in other languages.  Added offsets, I can't imagine you would need anything else.

Comment: The solution was to use the attribute "Object_Size" instead of "Size". "Size" returns the minimal amount of space required to store a structure, but "Object_Size" returns the actual number of bits it uses.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475819/ada-variant-size-in-record-type

Comment: Do not call `GetLastError` unless instructed to. In this specific case, the value returned from `GetLastError` is only meaningful, if [`GetRawInputDeviceList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645598.aspx) returns `(UINT)-1`. For all other values returned the `GetLastError` value is meaningless, if not misleading.

Comment: @IInspectable: It's perfectly alright to call `GetLastError` needlessly.  You're right that it is not useful in this case.  But better to have the value and not need it, than need the value and not have it.

Comment: When you say that it's *"better to have **the** value"* you seem to imply that there is only ever **one** value in case of success. This is not the case. The value returned by `GetLastError` is random, and having a random value without knowing that it is, is misleading at best. Calling `GetLastError` does nothing to harm the application. However, it produces a value, and having a value - however random - will affect future actions. The least you should do is augment the output and add *"(ignore, unless <some other value> is -1)"* where appropriate.

Comment: @IInspectable: The definite article is correct because `GetLastError` does not have a multivalued (aggregate) return type.  There is only one value returned from one call to `GetLastError`.  It certainly is not random either. It is the value last passed to `SetLastError`.  I don't feel that there's any need to repeat the documentation in the output.  Look at this as a dump of the state of the program after the function call.  The debugger doesn't put "(but you should ignore this)" if you put `errno` in the Watch window.

Comment: There is a difference between you putting `@err,hr` in the Watch window and your colleague reading your debug output. The colleague will be thankful for the hint. *Random* is the colloquial term used to describe the phenomenon, that the outcome of the same operation can be different on different invocations. This is precisely what happens here: If you run your code repeatedly, the return value from `GetLastError` can be different for different successful invocations of `GetRawInputDeviceList`.